# Environment Variables not propagating into Gradle test environment

Tags: gradle, environment-variables, test-environments

I'm trying to run a Gradle build, and am restricted to using version 1.8. I have some tests that require environment variables to be set, but they keep failing. I used the following code to debug:

```
test {
    println System.getenv("PATH")
}
```

And it prints out the correct value. However, it looks like this isn't persisting through to the test environment, as it continues to fail because the appropriate data cannot be found. Is there anything in particular that must be done in order to have the process' environment variables be passed through to the test VM's environment variables?

I am aware that after Gradle 2.0 you can use

```
environment [var] [value]
```

to set test environment variables, but as I said, I am restricted to 1.8.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This can most definitely be done with [Gradle 1.8](https://docs.gradle.org/1.8/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:environment(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

```
test {
  environment 'NAME', 'VALUE'
}
```